# I need a MySQL query to be optimized

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization

I have a query running on MySQL DB and is very slow.

Is there anyway I can optimize the following

```
SELECT mcm.merchant_name,
   ( ( Sum(ot.price) + Sum(ot.handling_charges)
       + Sum(ot.sales_tax_recd)
       + Sum(ot.shipping_cost) - Sum(ot.sales_tax_payable) ) -
     Sum(im.break_even_cost) ) AS PL,
   ot.merchant_id
   FROM   order_table ot,
          item_master im,
          merchant_master mcm
   WHERE  ot.item_id = im.item_id
   AND ot.merchant_id = mcm.merchant_id
   GROUP  BY mcm.merchant_name
   ORDER  BY pl DESC
   LIMIT  0, 10;
```

The Above Query is taking more than 200 seconds to execute.

Explain Result:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys           key         key_len     ref                     rows        Extra   
1   SIMPLE      ot      ALL     "merchant_id,item_id"   NULL        NULL        NULL                    507910      "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1   SIMPLE      mcm     eq_ref  "PRIMARY,merchant_id"   PRIMARY     4           stores.ot.merchant_id   1   
1   SIMPLE      im      eq_ref  "PRIMARY,item_id"       PRIMARY     4           stores.ot.item_id       1
```

Also, I got Error-1003 when I run EXPLAIN EXTENDED

Comment: You should post output of this query with "EXPLAIN EXTENDED" prefix (EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT mcm.merchant_name,...)

Comment: This will tend to be more of an schema design question, the query it self isn't anything too over the top.

Comment: `id select_type table type possible_keys   key   key_len  ref      rows  Extra 
1 SIMPLE  ot  ALL  "merchant_id,item_id" NULL  NULL  NULL     507910  "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1 SIMPLE  mcm  eq_ref "PRIMARY,merchant_id" PRIMARY  4   stores.ot.merchant_id 1 
1 SIMPLE  im  eq_ref "PRIMARY,item_id"  PRIMARY  4   stores.ot.item_id  1 `

Comment: @user2992030 please add that to your post and make it readable

Comment: looks like there are no indexes on `merchant_id` and `item_id` in `order_table`.

Comment: Also, I got Error-1003 when I run EXPLAIN EXTENDED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [mysql explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) plan to find out why it is taking so long and then maybe create some indexes or change your code.

**Update**
Based upon this make sure you have an composite index on the order_table on `merchant_id,item_id`

Comment: `id select_type table type possible_keys   key   key_len  ref      rows  Extra 
1 SIMPLE  ot  ALL  "merchant_id,item_id" NULL  NULL  NULL     507910  "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1 SIMPLE  mcm  eq_ref "PRIMARY,merchant_id" PRIMARY  4   stores.ot.merchant_id 1 
1 SIMPLE  im  eq_ref "PRIMARY,item_id"  PRIMARY  4   stores.ot.item_id  1 
`

Comment: I've added Explain result to Question